# Oracleデータ移行におけるDBサイズの試算方法

Tags: oracle

Oracle 12cからOracle 19cに対しデータ移行を行うにあたり、バージョンによるシステムスキーマの数・容量が異なるため、19cをインストールするサーバのディスク容量の試算方法がわからず困っています。19c構築時にデフォルト容量を確認してからディスクサイズを決定できればよいのですが、当然そのようなわけにはいかず、設計する段階で予め検証環境等を用意してシステムスキーマ分の差分容量を把握しておくしかないのでしょうか。

移行にはData Pumpを使用し、fullモードでデータベース全体の移行を行う予定です。
ちなみに、エクスポート/インポート時の実行コマンドは以下のようなものを想定しています。

`expdp system/<password> full=y dumpfile=<directory_name>:<dumpfile_name>.dmp`

`impdp system/<password> full=y dumpfile=<directory_name>:<dumpfile_name>.dmp`

移行に慣れられている方がいらっしゃいましたら、通常当たり前に取られている方法や気を配られているポイントについてご教授頂けますと幸いです。

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 参考までに現状のデータでどれくらいのサイズなのかの情報はあった方がよさそうなのと、移行後に全くデータは増えないのか、それとも「次の移行」までにどれくらいデータが増えるのか…といったところも考慮する必要がありそうです。